# LSTM: different number of rows at each time step

Tags: keras, rnn, lstm

I have for each of the years N-k, ..., N a different data set. The data sets have the same number of columns but a different number of rows. The columns have the same meanings in the different datasets. One of the columns is the target.

The rows in the various datasets in no way correspond to each other. The 10th row in the 3rd dataset is not fundamentally connected to the 10th row in the 4th dataset - or any of the other rows. In future years' data sets, the rows will likewise be unconnected to the rows in the previous years' datasets.

Is LSTM even an option for solving this kind of problem?

Help appreciated.